# Enviar Mail desde Sitio MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Buenas noches compañeros, espero me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente. Tengo una vista donde cargo una lista de usuarios, se en-listan el nombre, id, mail etc. Lo que quiero hacer es poner un botón en cada campo de esta lista y al darle clic envié un correo al Email correspondiente.

Model:

```
    public class XYZViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Usuarios()
    {
        List<XYZViewModel> Lista;
        using (dbcontext dc = new dbcontext())
        {
                Lista= (from a in dc.TblUsers
                        select new XYZViewModel
                        {
                            Id = a.ID,
                            Name = a.Name,
                            Mail = a.Email
                        }).ToList();
        }
            return View(Lista);
    }
```

Vista

```
@model List<MVCProject.Models.XYZViewModel>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Correo</th>
                        <th>Enviar Mail</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var abc in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@abc.Id</td>
                            <td>@abc.Name</td>
                            <td>@abc.Mail</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Enviar" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

La lista se carga bien en la vista pero no se como poder ligar cada botón al correo en listado. Espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero tienes que cambiar tu boton de tipo submit por un boton "normal", el submit solamente es para enviar una `form` completa

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Enviar" />
```

Lo cambias por un input de tipo button con un id y un data para guardar el correo

```
<input type="button" id="buttonCorreo" data-Mail="@abc.Mail" class="btn btn-default" value="Enviar" />
```

Luego generas un evento de click en jquery donde a traves de un Ajax mandaras llamar un Action para enviar el correo

```
<script>
        $("button#buttonCorreo").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var correo = $(this).attr("data-Mail");

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Controller/EnviarCorreo/" + correo,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

                    if (response.respuesta) {
                        alert('Correo Enviado');
                    } else {
                        alert('Error');
                    }

                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Y generar tu Action en tu controller

```
public JsonResult DeleteJson(string id)
{

     //Logica de envio de correo

  return Json(new {respuesta=true});

}
```

Espero haberte orientado y ayudado